# failed to create trigger Error Code: 1363. There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am using these as a practice

Main table:

```
create table emp 
(
    emp_id int(5) primary key,
    e_name varchar(30),
    e_title varchar(20),
    e_salary decimal(10, 2)
);
```

Log/audit table:

```
create table emp_log
(
    tracking_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    change_type varchar(30),
    change_occured_at VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    old_value INT NOT NULL,
    new_value INT NOT NULL,
    modified DATETIME NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar(50)
);
```

After creating these tables, I was trying to create triggers for the main table to create a log in the log table I tried these triggers all my triggers should work **after** changes made by the {INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE}

Here is my trigger code; from what I understand from the example presented in the internet, the triggers I have are all after triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger ai_emp_log after insert on emp for each row
begin
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
select user() into vUser;
if (new.e_name!=old.e_name) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('insert',emp.emp_id,'record_not_present',new.emp.e_name,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_title!=old.e_title) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('insert',emp.emp_id, 'record_not_present',new.emp.e_tile,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_salary!=old.e_salary) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('insert',emp.emp_id, 'record_not_present',new.emp.e_salary,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
end;
DELIMITER;

DELIMITER $$
create trigger au_emp_log after update on emp for each row
begin
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
select user() into vUser;
if (new.e_name!=old.e_name) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('update',emp.emp_id, old.e_name,new.e_name,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_title!=old.e_title) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('update',emp.emp_id, old.e_title,new.e_tile,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_salary!=old.e_salary) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('update',emp.emp_id, old.e_salary,new.e_salary,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
end;
DELIMITER;

DELIMITER $$
create trigger ad_emp_log after delete on emp for each row
begin
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
select user() into vUser;
if (new.e_name!=old.e_name) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('delete',emp.emp_id, old.e_name,'record_deleted',SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_title!=old.e_title) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('delete',emp.emp_id, old.e_title,'record_deleted',SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_salary!=old.e_salary) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('delete',emp.emp_id, old.e_salary,'record_deleted',SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
end;
DELIMITER;
```

help me by correcting the mistakes I made in the trigger code as I get these error when I try to run them
this is the output log from MySQL when I tried to run the code

> 16:41:32   create trigger au_emp_log after update on emp for each row begin DECLARE vUser varchar(50); select user() into vUser; if (new.e_name!=old.e_name) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('update',emp.emp_id, old.e_name,new.e_name,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; if (new.e_title!=old.e_title) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('update',emp.emp_id, old.e_title,new.e_tile,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; if (new.e_salary!=old.e_salary) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('update',emp.emp_id, old.e_salary,new.e_salary,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; end; DELIMITER; Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'e_tile' in 'NEW'  0.140 sec

> 16:41:46   create trigger ad_emp_log after delete on emp for each row begin DECLARE vUser varchar(50); select user() into vUser; if (new.e_name!=old.e_name) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('delete',emp.emp_id, old.e_name,new.e_name,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; if (new.e_title!=old.e_title) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('delete',emp.emp_id, old.e_title,new.e_tile,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; if (new.e_salary!=old.e_salary) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('delete',emp.emp_id, old.e_salary,new.e_salary,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; end; DELIMITER; Error Code: 1363. There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger  0.000 sec

> 16:44:50   create trigger ai_emp_log after insert on emp for each row begin DECLARE vUser varchar(50); select user() into vUser; if (new.e_name!=old.e_name) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('insert',emp.emp_id,'record_not_present',new.emp.e_name,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; if (new.e_title!=old.e_title) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('insert',emp.emp_id, 'record_not_present',new.emp.e_tile,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; if (new.e_salary!=old.e_salary) then insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by)  values('insert',emp.emp_id, 'record_not_present',new.emp.e_salary,SYSDATE(),vUser); end if; end; DELIMITER;   Error Code: 1363. There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger  0.000 sec

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. The syntax, however, is clearly not T-SQL, so this is not SQL Server.

Comment: What does this have to do with logging?

Comment: @Parsifal i want to create a trigger to the table so if changes occur it records the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few more digging around i had the trigger working. so thought I would share it with you guys who might face a similar situation might be helpful for them or work as an example/reference for their work

**after insert trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger ai_emp_log after insert on emp for each row
begin
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
select user() into vUser;

insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('insert',new.emp_id,"no old value",new.e_name,SYSDATE(),vUser);

insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('insert',new.emp_id,"no old value",new.e_title,SYSDATE(),vUser);

insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('insert',new.emp_id,"no old value",new.e_salary,SYSDATE(),vUser);

end;
DELIMITER;
```

**after update trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger au_emp_log after update on emp for each row
begin
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
select user() into vUser;
if (new.e_name!=old.e_name) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('update',new.emp_id, old.e_name,new.e_name,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_title!=old.e_title) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('update',new.emp_id, old.e_title,new.e_title,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
if (new.e_salary!=old.e_salary) then
insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('update',emp_id, old.e_salary,new.e_salary,SYSDATE(),vUser);
end if;
end;
DELIMITER;
```

**after delete trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger ad_emp_log after delete on emp for each row
begin
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
select user() into vUser;

insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('delete',old.emp_id, old.e_name,"value deleted",SYSDATE(),vUser);

insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('delete',old.emp_id, old.e_title,"value deleted",SYSDATE(),vUser);

insert into emp_log(change_type,change_occured_at,old_value,new_value,modified,created_by) 
values('delete',old.emp_id, old.e_salary,"value deleted",SYSDATE(),vUser);

end;
DELIMITER;
```

Here the output of the test I done

[image: output of the test]

Answer (score 1):

1. ai_emp_log - We don't have 'OLD' row in insert trigger. We only have 'NEW' row there.

2.au_emp_log - Its e_title, not 'e_tile'

3.ad_emp_log - We don't have 'NEW' row in delete trigger. We are removing a row, not creating new one.

Refer this to get an idea about triggers.
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-trigger

Comment: hey if can provide an example for ai_emp_log and ad_emp_log much appreciated I did check the site u suggested  but I felt like the example present there is not helpful for me to understand it, so if you suggestion in the form of an example for my code, please do keep your suggestion